# Speeding up Python Script tools get of raster properties using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.2, performance

I am using python script tools for ArcGIS 10.2, under Windows 8.1 64bit.

When I am using the arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management() command, it's very slow to process the data.

For example. I tried to get the maximum value for 14 rasters, if I use the batch mode of the system tool: Get Raster Properties, it uses only 0.19 seconds.

But when I am using python script tools to do this, it basically takes 1 second to print 1 value on the screen. So it takes 15 seconds to get the maximum value of the 14 rasters. So when I have hundreds of rasters to process, it takes too much time.

And this is when the CPU usage is 20%, which is the maximum usage when running ArcGIS on my laptop, sometimes the CPU couldn't even get there, when the usage is only 5 or 6%, it takes one minute to get all the values.

this is the code I use for this part:

```
for out_raster in out_rasters:
    try:
        raster_min = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(out_raster,"MINIMUM")
        raster_min = raster_min.getOutput(0)
        arcpy.AddMessage(raster_min)
    except:
        arcpy.AddMessage("No_data")
```

Is there any way I can increase the speed?

Comment: What is the os architecture you are with- 32 or 64? If 64 then have you installed "ArcGIS for Desktop Background Geoprocessing (64 bit)"?

Comment: Make sure you have the script tool set to run in-process. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000000r000000

Comment: @msi_g Yes I'm using the 64bit Windows 8.1. After installing the  "ArcGIS for Desktop Background Geoprocessing (64 bit)", all geoprocessings are now running in foreground, even though the background geoprocessing is Enabled in the Geoprocessing Options. And the speed for GetRasterProperties_management is still slow

Comment: Yes, the run in-process is checked.

Comment: The system tool may be written in ArcObjects or C code which would run faster than a arcpy script which just adds another step before eventially calling the ArcObject or C code.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try cutting out ArcPy by converting it to an array and then using [numpy's minimum function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html).

Answer (score 1):

You ask, '*so is there any way I can increase the speed?*'

Geoprocessing calls like `arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management()` are slow calls. Using the `arcpy` objects, in this case `Raster` and accessing its property `minimum` will generally (most likely always) be faster.

Specifically one way to speed your script up would be to use:

```
raster_minimum = arcpy.Raster(path).minimum
```

to get the minimum value. Quick testing on my machine in looping over raster paths and using your method:

```
arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management('[raster_path]',"MINIMUM")`
raster_min = raster_min.getOutput(0)
```

took twice as long to complete each call as the `Raster` object method.

Answer (score 0):

Orion, I just noticed you mentioned in your response to msi_g that even after installing 64-bit Background Geoprocessing that your tool is still running in the foreground.

By default, all models and script tools run in the foreground, which means by default they all run in a 32-bit environment.

Have you unchecked the "Always run in foreground" checkbox on your general properties tab of your script tool?

If not, in the Catalog or ArcToolbox window, right-click your tool and click Properties. On the General tab, uncheck Always run in foreground and click OK.

Next, make sure Background Geoprocessing is actually enabled. On the ArcMap menu, click Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing Options. On the Background Processing pane, check Enable.

Comment: Yes, I unchecked the Always run in foreground, and checked the Enable for Background Processing. Now not only python script tools are running on foreground, the system tools are also running on foreground. And any thoughts on increasing the speed of "GetRasterProperties_management"?

Comment: My initial thought was to create a describe object and interrogate that but the min values cannot be obtained from a Raster dataset that way. Next suggestion would be to use a python toolbox instead. I'm not positive that script tools can actually leverage the 64-bit background GP libraries. I just don't know because I haven't used script tools since 9.3. Once Python toolboxes came out, I never looked back. It's curious though that even your system tools are running in foreground. If background GP Is installed and enabled, the definitely shouldn't be happening.